# R sort multiple (linked) list

Tags: r

I encountered this problem, I have two lists which have the same dimension (or the same number of elements), and they are linked.

For example, one list stores the ID number of the students, while another one stores the exam marks of these students.

I want to sort the exam marks from small to large, but I do not want to loose the one-to-one link between students ID and their marks. How can I do so in R ?

Comment: Can you update your question with some details (possibly code) about the exact data structure you are using?  The answer to your question might be to switch to a data structure which can tolerate sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume a list like this:

```
a <- list(id = c("c", "a", "b"), score = c(2, 9, 12))
> a
$id
[1] "c" "a" "b"

$score
[1]  2  9 12
```

Then you can sort it using `lapply`...

```
> lapply(a, function(x)x[order(a$id)])
$id
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$score
[1]  9 12  2

> lapply(a, function(x)x[order(a$score, decreasing=TRUE)])
$id
[1] "b" "a" "c"

$score
[1] 12  9  2
```